# Creating a development like the one for three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am very interested in creating something similar to the example shown here
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYGzsM4snmg
Can any tell me if the source is available or give a high level walk through assuming I am three.js noob.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gource/

Comment: Thank you! did not see this earlier

Comment: I was assuming this was written in three.js, guess that explains why Mr.Doob did not post it on the examples link.
Also the fact that the license is GNU does not help.
Guess I will have to try and take a stab at writing my own using three.js

Answer (score 2):

If You read the video description you will see this link

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/

Open the link try to find the project you are interested in and click it. Once the page is loaded. You Can right click on the page and click on inspect element if you are using safari or google chrome. You will find the javascript code needed to built the application and you can download the three.js minified version and include it in your project. Or you can visit this link to download the source code.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Hope This is Helpful.

Comment: Mohammad thank for your response but the sample is not on either of these locations